# Killing multiple GNU screen sessions with the same name

Tags: gnu-screen, kill

Sometimes my script bugs out and multiple screen sessions with the same name get created. Is there a way to kill all of these with this name in one command?

```
Rx:/scripts# screen -S haydoz-script -X quit
There are several suitable screens on:
        13372.haydoz-script     (09/10/11 07:44:05)     (Detached)
        12287.haydoz-script     (09/10/11 07:30:45)     (Detached)
        12230.haydoz-script     (09/10/11 07:17:42)     (Detached)
        7824.haydoz-script      (09/09/11 11:42:26)     (Detached)
        7764.haydoz-script      (09/09/11 11:35:40)     (Detached)
        15753.haydoz-script     (09/04/11 15:00:27)     (Detached)
        15744.haydoz-script     (09/04/11 15:00:26)     (Detached)
```

There are other screens running besides these ones that I do not want to kill.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If there are no other `screen` sessions running you can use the "hard" way and just `kill` them with `killall screen`.

If you want to be nice you can iterate over your list of screen sessions and kill them one after another:

```
# screen -S foo && screen -S foo
[detached]
[detached]
# screen -ls
There are screens on:                                                                                                                                                                                      
        8350.foo        (Detached)                                                                                                                                                                         
        8292.foo        (Detached)                                                                                                                                                                         
2 Sockets in /tmp/screens/S-joschi.                                                                                                                                                                        

# This is the interesting line. Just replace "foo" with the name of your session(s)
# for session in $(screen -ls | grep -o '[0-9]*\.foo'); do screen -S "${session}" -X quit; done
# screen -ls
No Sockets found in /tmp/screens/S-joschi.
```

Comment: unfortunately, there are other screens that I don't want killed.

Comment: That's why I also provided a "nice" version. ;)

Comment: The 'nice' version doesn't work for me

Answer (score 4):

`screen -ls "$SESSION_NAME"` lists the full names of matching sessions on tab-indented lines. So you can iterate on these lines, extract the full names, and call the `quit` command on each matching name.

```
SESSION_NAME='haydoz-script'
screen -ls "$SESSION_NAME" | (
  IFS=$(printf '\t');
  sed "s/^$IFS//" |
  while read -r name stuff; do
      screen -S "$name" -X quit
  done
)
```

Comment: What is `stuff`?

Comment: @user53145 The variable that contains words of the output from `screen -ls` after the first which is the session name. If you wrote `read -r name stuff` then `name` would contain the whole line (except the leading spaces), but we only want the first word.

Comment: What type of file is this? How do I run it. Typing it in console won't work

Comment: @JackNicholson This is a shell snippet. It should run on any sh-style shell (dash, bash, ksh, zsh, …).

Comment: Thank you I'm amazed your code worked! Had trouble with this for ages. Thank you. I ended up putting it in a .sh file and running `sh kill.sh`

Comment: That's one of the most amazing things I've read. I just learned a lot about shell scripting.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one-liner. You need to replace `your_session` with required one.

`screen -ls your_session | grep -E '\s+[0-9]+\.' | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}' | while read s; do screen -XS $s quit; done`

Answer (score -2):

Attach to screen and then run another screen command:

```
screen -x "Name" -x -X kill
```

Comment: There are multiple screens with this Name. So kill them by this command does not work!